# Simulate parallelism in Lua

Tags: lua, parallel-processing, prototype

I am trying to use lua to prototype some parallel algorithm. With this I mean to write code in pure Lua, perform tests on it, debug it, etc. Then, when I am confident that it works, I can translate it to a true multithread library, or even to another language (e.g. OpenCL kenel). Obviously I am not concerned in any way with the performance of the prototype code.

I thought to use a coroutine that yield at each line, with some boilerplate to randomly select the next "Thread" to run. For example:

```
local function parallel_simulation(...)

  local function_list = {...}
  local coroutine_list = {}
  local thread_number = #function_list
  for i = 1, thread_number do
    coroutine_list[i] = coroutine.create(function_list[i])
  end

  while 0 < thread_number do

    local current = math.random(1, thread_number)
    local worker = coroutine_list[current]

    coroutine.resume(worker)

    if 'dead' == coroutine.status(worker) then
      thread_number = thread_number - 1
      table.remove(coroutine_list, current)
    end
  end
end

----------------------------------------------------------
-- Usage example

local Y = coroutine.yield
local max = 3
local counter = 0
local retry = 99

local function increment()
  Y() local c = counter
  Y() while max > c do
  Y()   c = counter
  Y()   c = c + 1
  Y()   counter = c
  Y() end
end

for i=1,retry do
  counter = 0
  parallel_simulation(increment, increment)
  if max ~= counter then
    print('Test SUCCESS ! A non-thread-safe algorithm was identified .', i, counter)
    return
  end
end

error('Test FAIL ! The non-thread-safe algorithm was not identified .')
```

This is just an idea, any solution involving pure Lua is welcome! What makes me very uncomfortable with this solution, are all that Y(). Is there any way to avoid them? (debug.sethook does not allow to yield...)

EDIT 1 - More meaningful example was provided

EDIT 2 - Hopefully, I clearified what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to pass control after every line.

Comment: In a parallel execution you do not know exactly the instruction execution order, so I want my code behave in the same way. For example I want to simulate concurrent value write to spot the need of a mutex. Obviously I can put the yield only on the critical line, but the whole point is that probably I do not know which is the critical code. Let's say that the next step should be to yield after each VM instruction code (of a under-test chunk).

Comment: I don't understand why this is useful when you could, say, simply, make a `sleep` function which will wait for so long letting another task cut in until they sleep, etc.

Comment: If for "Task" you mean another system process, it is not what I want, I want a race condition from the same process (the standalone "Interpreter" one). If you mean "Lua function/coroutine" instead, the lua execution model is not preemptive, i.e. no other coroutine can be executed untill the active one calls coroutine.yield. A sleep will simply stop the program for a given admount of time with no chance that other coroutine (or part of) can be executed.

Comment: I mean why not make a multithreader that switches tasks while one is sleeping for so long. I don't see any legitimate reason to run a tash, break at a line, run another, etc. that's inefficient and frankly, not that useful.

Comment: Any solution involving pure lua (and pure lua modules) is ok for me, it does not have to be implement with coroutines. Them were just my first thought. Well, actually, I still do not see other ways to obtain the same result... what do you mean for "Make a multithreader"? As far as I know it is impossible in pure lua. Can you provide me an example?

Comment: I feel like I'm doing a bad job at communicating right now, and I apologize for that. But what I'm *trying* to say is that wouldn't it be better, than to switch threads after every line, to break it up into chunks? Say thread1 does so much work, but then you feel like it needs to wait for, say, 5 seconds before continuing, and let other tasks do their work during this time? e.g. Only one thread at a time will execute, but it shifts between them efficiently, when there's spare time.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding; for sure what you are proprosing is a good way to design an application. But I am interested in _simulate_ multithreading in order to prototype-test-debug algorithms. It is somehow more general. With that infrastructure, for example, I will able to simulate an application designed as you are proposing, as well as OpenCL kernels (where all the "Threads" are heavy by definition). Take a look at the new example I added and suppose I am not aware of the problem. With that tool I can recognize that `increment()` has a bug and I can search for a solution.

Comment: I fail to see a practical use for this system. Why would switching threads line by line be helpful in any scenario? Compared to what I suggested?

Comment: I still not understand what you are suggesting. Please write some code otherwise we will stuck in this misunderstanding loop.

Comment: Something like this: http://hawwashsoft.proboards.com/thread/210/multithreading

Comment: It do not seems provide me any solution to my problem. I tryed to `NewTask(increment) NewTask(increment) Scheduler:Start()`: it fails the test not reporting any problem. The point is, I am not interested in "When" interrupt the thread (for now), but that the interruption should _simulate_ a preemptive one i.e. it can happen without an explicit request. To be clear: as you said, this is not usefull at all in designing an application, but since the real hardware works in that way, I need my code to behave like that in order to _simulate_ it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative to putting `Y()` in front of each line is to use `gsub` and `load`:

```
Y = coroutine.yield
max = 3
counter = 0

code = [[
function increment()
  local c = counter
  while max > c do
    c = counter
    c = c + 1
    counter = c
  end
end]]
code = code:gsub("\n  ", "\n  Y() ") -- replace two spaces in find/replace with whatever tab character(s) you use
assert(load(code))()

local retry = 99
-- rest of code here
```

(Use `load` or `loadstring` depending on your Lua version)
Note that the variable declarations Y/max/counter must be global or else the loaded function will not have access to them. Similarly, the function in `code` must be global or else `increment` will not exist outside the loaded code.

Such a solution assumes that all instructions on each line are atomic/thread-safe, of course.

An improvement I would recommend making to `parallel_simulation` is to add some way of changing how the next thread is chosen. ex, perhaps the error will only be revealed if one of the threads is early on in execution and another one is almost done - though this state could theoretically be reached through sufficient random trials, having an argument that allows you to adjust which threads are more likely to be chosen next (ex using weights) should make it much more likely.